# PHP Chart.js page not showing chart

Tags: javascript, php, html, chart.js

I have a page chart.php which contains a Chart.js bar chart. If I make this the index file of my webserver, it displays fine.

However, I am now trying to load this page from the index.php file, in order to have the chart reload continuously.

Separately, both files work perfectly. But when I have the index.php opening the chart.php, the text outside of the chart displays, but there's a blank white space where the chart should be.

index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload=setInterval();>
<body>
<div id="demo">
</div>
<script>
var myVar = setInterval(loadDoc, 1000);
function loadDoc() {
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
        xhttp.open("GET", "chart.php", true);
        xhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
</body>
</html>
```

chart.php:

```
<?php
  $db = new SQLite3('/var/www/html/newdb.db');
  $result = ($db->query('SELECT * FROM NUMBERS'));

  $avg_stack = array();
  $name_stack = array();

  while ($res = $result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)){
    $avg = $res["AVG"];
    $name = $res["NAME"];
    echo ("<br>");
    echo($name . ": " . $avg);
    array_push($avg_stack, $avg);
    array_push($name_stack, $name);
  }

  $db->close();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.c
ss">
  <title>My Chart.js Chart</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="demo" class="container">
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
    <input type="button" value="Add Data" onclick="adddata()">
  </div>

  <script>
    var data_array = [<?php echo '"'.implode('","', $avg_stack).'"' ?>];
    var name_array = [<?php echo '"'.implode('","', $name_stack).'"' ?>];

    var colour_array = [];

    var dynamicColour = function() {
            var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
            var g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
            var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
            return "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";
    };

    for (var i in data_array) {
        colour_array.push(dynamicColour());
    }

    let myChart = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
        let massPopChart = new Chart(myChart, {
                  type:'bar', // bar, horizontalBar, pie, line, doughnut, radar, polarArea
                  data:{
                        labels:name_array,
                        datasets:[{
                          label:'Population',
                          data:data_array,
                          backgroundColor:colour_array,
                          borderWidth:1,
                          borderColor:'#777',
                          hoverBorderWidth:3,
                          hoverBorderColor:'#000'
                        }]
                  },
                  options:{
                  }
                });
        function adddata() {
                var newposition = data_array.length;
                data_array.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 700000) + 5000);
                colour_array.push(dynamicColour());
                massPopChart.data.datasets[0].data[newposition] = data_array[newposition];
                massPopChart.data.labels[newposition] = "Newly Added";
                massPopChart.update();
        }

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The initial echo($name . ": " . $avg); displays fine, and the button appears fine, but no chart. Again, works perfectly when making the chart.php the index.php.

Comment: Any errors on browser console?

Comment: Yes there is one, "TypeError: Not enough arguments to Window.setInterval."

Comment: Chart.js and Chart.css should be loaded in index.php. Furthermore, there should be not <html>,<head> and <body> tag in chart.php. There must be just the HTML that would be populated in DOM element ID "demo". Please update the code in your post accordingly and let me know if the issues still persist.

Comment: The reason I've had the chart.js in a separate file is to have it continually refresh to reflect updates to the SQLite database. Should I be putting it into the index.html somehow? And removing the <html>,<head> and <body> tags and their content in the chart.php caused the chart to not show even when loading the chart.php page directly (which works with those tags still in).

Comment: Fixed by simply using setInterval(function(){ } to check the database for changes instead.